# Enable cluster mode on AWS ElastiCache Redis cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

I have an ElastiCache Redis (cluster mode disabled) Cluster and would like to change to an ElastiCache Redis (cluster mode enabled) Cluster. I haven't found a way to do this, but also have not found a statement that it is not possible either. This is complicated by the confusing language around 'cluster' and 'cluster mode'.

[This document from Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Replication.CreatingReplGroup.ExistingCluster.html) states that:

> Currently, Redis (cluster mode enabled) does not support creating a
>   cluster with replicas using an available single-node cluster.

This somewhat implies that it can be done from a cluster with multiple nodes.

Similarly, [this document about modifying a cluster](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Replication.Modify.html) says:

> You can modify a Redis (cluster mode disabled) cluster's settings using the ElastiCache console, the AWS CLI, or the ElastiCache API. Currently, ElastiCache does not support modifying a Redis (cluster mode enabled) replication group except by creating a backup of the current replication group then using that backup to seed a new Redis (cluster mode enabled) replication group.

Again, this implies that you can change a Redis (cluster mode disabled) cluster but doesn't really say one way or another. Though, I get the idea from this statement that I'd need to back up the current Redis (cluster mode disabled) cluster and then use that to seed a new Redis (cluster mode enabled) cluster.

Comment: I've been looking for this info in the docs as well. They should state it clearly in some place.

Answer (score 3):

You have to provision a new cluster with "Cluster" mode enabled, what you want is unfortunately not possible.

You data though can be backed up to S3, and used to seed the newly created system.

Comment: But only if the backup contains only one database, otherwise you may get an error like this...

2022-11-25 2:53 PM UTC Restore from snapshot failed for node group 0002 in replication group test-cluster-0. To restore a snapshot in cluster mode, all keys in the RDB file should reside in DB 0. Snapshot ID: preclustermodeupgrade-221125