# How to disable cluster mode on a AWS Elasticache Redis

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache, redis-cluster

I have an AWS Elasticache with Cluster Mode enabled. Ideally, I just want to "turn off" cluster mode. How can I do this? Additionally, it is desirable to retain the data I currently have.

I have already tried:

1. Update the `Parameter group` from `default.redis6.x.cluster.on` to `default.redis6.x`, but it gives the error: `The parameter cluster-enabled has a different value in the requested parameter group than the current parameter group. This parameter value cannot be changed for a cache cluster.`
2. Backing up the cluster, creating a new instance with cluster mode off, from the backup - Could not accomplish that, when I try to restore from backup, I don't have the option to create with cluster mode disabled. My guess is that not all commands from cluster mode are available on Redis instance, and the backups are not compatible. [From the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/backups-seeding-redis.html): You can't seed a Redis (cluster mode disabled) cluster from an .rdb file created from a Redis (cluster mode enabled) cluster.

Is there a way to "convert" an Redis cluster arrangement into a Redis with cluster mode disabled?

P.S.: In this other question [Enable cluster mode on AWS ElastiCache Redis cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47394943/enable-cluster-mode-on-aws-elasticache-redis-cluster), the only answer talk about backup and restore, which I tried and didn't work. Besides, I want the opposite, to disable cluster mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this using the built-in mechanisms of ElastiCache.
You should consider https://developer.redis.com/riot/riot-redis/ which has the capability to copy data between two different clusters. I think it will do exactly what you need.